# Как изменить вид товара в woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

[image]Столкнулся с такой проблемой, хочу сделать свой вид товаров, но не могу найти в каком файле можно сделать изменения.
Скажите кто знает?

Answer (score 1):

В файле

```
woocommerce.css
```

Путь

```
сам сайт/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css
```

Также некоторые изменения можно вносить в файл

```
style.css`
```

`

Comment: Мне нужно именно доступ к div